# How can I get Crashlytics to send logs of normal sessions (without app crash)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, crash-reports, crashlytics

I've seen suggestions of using **[CrashlyticsKit recordError:error]**, but that is not enough in my case as I need the whole console log of every session.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to send all messages from logs?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Yes.

Comment: Take a look if this link can help you: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: @JuanThat's not what I'm looking for. They are customising crash reports. I want all sessions reports not only the sessions where there is a crash..